# Check if list variable is empty in Windows batch

Tags: batch-file, testing, is-empty

I have the program below (simplified).

The fact is that `table` variable can contain none, one or several string values:

```
set table=
REM set table=geo1
REM set table=geo1,geo2,geo3

if [%table%]==[] (goto :end)

for %%a in %table% do (

    REM Some commands...

)

:end

REM Some commands...
```

If `table=` or `table=geo1`, no problem. The program is behaving as wanted.

If `table=geo1,geo2,geo3` (several values), the program is closing immediatly even with a `pause` command at the end.

Is there a simple way to check wether a variable is empty or not, being an array or a single string?

Comment: Your variable is not an [array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure), but a _list_. An [array variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990) should use square braquets this way: `array[1]=first element of array`

Comment: Good point @Aacini! I've changed the question title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that a comma, like <kbd>space</kbd> is a default separator, so `cmd` interprets

```
if [%table%]==[] (goto :end)
```

as (eg)

```
if [geo1 geo2 geo3]==[] (goto :end)
```

hence it sees `geo2` where it's expecting a comparison operator, generates an error message and terminates the batch. If you are running directly from the prompt, you'd see the message.

The way to determine whether a variable is `set` is

```
if defined variablename .....
```

or

```
if not "%variablename%"=="" .....
```

where `"quoting a string containing separators"` solves the problem with contained-spaces, the sae wy as it does for file/directorynames.

Answer (score 2):

You get syntax errors at two points, where the commas does not what you want.

First problem is the `if` command. Also there is a better syntax (see below)
Second problem is the `for` command. There is a better syntax, too (see below)
Another possible problem is the `set` command; there is a safer (and recommended syntax (see below)

```
rem set table=
REM set table=geo1
 set "table=geo1,geo2,geo3"
if "%table%"=="" (goto :end)
for %%a in (%table%) do (
    echo Some commands with %%a...
)
:end
```